# Annotating images with text for deep learning + NLP

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, tagging

I am looking for a way to label document images and at the same time annotate the text that is inside the bounding boxes. Do you know anything to do this task?
(I have the coordinates of the image text obtained by Google-vision-API response)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotation tools like: [PPOCRLabel](https://github.com/Evezerest/PPOCRLabel). This is a semi-automatic tool means it will auto-generate the text and you can edit them later.